# How to apply credit memo to invoice?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to apply a credit memo to an invoice, but there is a long list in the "apply" sublist and I'm not sure how to get the corresponding invoice # in the line.

Also I am having trouble even attempting to set the apply value as `true` with this line :

```
credit_memo_record_obj.setSublistValue({sublistId:'apply', fieldId:'apply', line: 0, value: true})
```

It tells me the sublist value doesn't exist and cant be changed.

I've also tried this approach from suiteanswers:

```js
var lineWithInvoice = credit_memo_record_obj.findSublistLineWithValue({
           sublistId: 'apply',
           fieldId: 'internalid',
           value: invoice_record_id
           });

           //Get Total amount of invoice
           var totalToPay = credit_memo_record_obj.getSublistValue({
               sublistId: 'apply',
               fieldId: 'total',
               line: lineWithInvoice
           });

           //Set apply to Truth (checkbox)
           credit_memo_record_obj.setSublistValue({
               sublistId: 'apply',
               fieldId: 'apply',
               line: lineWithInvoice,
               value: 'T'
           });
           credit_memo_record_obj.setSublistValue({
           sublistId: 'apply',
           fieldId: 'amount',
           line: lineWithInvoice,
           value: totalToPay
       });
```

This gives me:

> You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.

I tried testing with line 0 but it will have to be responsive to the corresponding invoice.

Can this be done? I can provide further clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Try the options below:

Option 1: Use a dynamic record (isDynamic: true)

```js
credit_memo_record_obj.selectLine({
    sublistId: 'apply',
    line: lineWithInvoice 
});
credit_memo_record_obj.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'apply',
    fieldId: 'apply',
    value: true
});
credit_memo_record_obj.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'apply'
});
```

Option 2: Use `record.transform`

Comment: I usually just use record.transform.  I find it the easiest method.